# Bookmark Firefox iMacros located in Dropbox?

Tags: firefox, bookmarks, imacros

I want to share/sync my iMacros (.iim) with my colleagues.

The default folder where iMacros-files run is here:

```
C:\Users\Lui\Documents\iMacros\Macros
```

The .iim file has the following name:

```
#example.iim
```

We can bookmark a iMacro in Firefox, for fast access.

```
imacros://run/?m=example.iim
```

If #example.iim is located in the default folder the iMacro will run with no problems.

Though, would rather have **some** of my iMacros located within Dropbox:

```
C:\Users\Lui\Dropbox\Company\Tech\Tools\iMacros\Macros
```

According to http://wiki.imacros.net/iMacros_for_Firefox#Bookmarking %5C stands for / and %23 stands for #.

Tried to bookmark that look like this:

```
imacros://run/?m=C%3A%5CUsers%5CLui%5CDropbox%5CCompany%5CTech%5CTools%5CiMacros%5CMacros%5C%23example.iim
```

But this gives me following error:

```
iMacros run command: macro C:\Users\Lui\Dropbox\Company\Tech\Tools\iMacros\Macros\#example.iim not found
```

Anyone know if this even is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check in the options of imacros.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNe8Z.png